# Passing Default State To Link When User Directly Navigates To The Page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

In my GatsbyJs app, I pass a parameter in the state through the `<Link/>` component. This parameter within the state tells which content to display once the user navigates to the page.

```
<Link
  to={`/${link}`}
  state={{ dataRef: dataToDisplay }}
  key={j}
>
  {heading}
</Link>
```

This works fine.

However, when the user directly navigates to the page (inserts the address in the addressbar), I get the error: `TypeError: _this.props.location.state is null`, because the state is empty.

**What I tried:**

On my `page` component, I tried to pass `default value` to the `this.props.location.state` in the form of:

`const { state = { dataRef: "foo" }} = this.props.location;`

However, this too didn't work & returned the same error. So my question is, how do I set default `dataRef` property within state, so that when the user types the page address directly within addressbar, the page loads with default parameters.

Thanks

Comment: You can not pass the state when user reloads, you can use query parameters

Answer (score 1):

```
const { state = { dataRef: "foo" }} = this.props.location;
```

This would had worked if `state` was `undefined`, but since it's `null` it will still be `null`. Have you tried something like this?

```
const state = this.props.location.state || { dataRef: "foo" }
```

Comment: yes I did. However, the solution was much simpler. All I did was use a ternary operator to check if state existed, if not then use a default value, otherwise use the state. Thank you for helping the Gatsby newbies with your time & support Derek, I am grateful.